# Changing image name in XAMPP database by using PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli, xampp

I have a form that the user could upload their image and write the id, I want the image to automatically rename to the id that they wrote in the form.The current code is able to rename the image according to the id in the folder to the desired id, however, i need the image name to change to the desired id in the database too, but the image name in the database is still the original name.

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,"ecom_product");
$msg = "";
//if upload button is pressed
if(isset($_POST['upload']))     
{
    // the path to store the uploaded image
    //$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$item_code = $_POST['code'];
$filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$source = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
$destination = "img/$item_code." . $extension;
move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);




    // Get all the submitted data from the form
    $item_code = $_POST['code'];
    $cat_name = $_POST['category'];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ecom_item (item_code, cat_name, item_name, image, text, price) VALUES ('$item_code','$cat_name','$item_name','$image','$text','$price')";
    mysqli_query($db,$sql); // stores the submitted data into the database table : item

    if(!is_dir("img/"))
    {
        mkdir("img/");
    }

    // move uploaded image to the folder : img



}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Upload With Description</title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formstyle.css">-->
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,"ecom_product");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ecom_item ORDER BY item_code ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
?>


    <center>
    <form name='show_item' action="exampleadditem.php" method='POST' align="center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2 align="center">View Item</h2>
    <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Add New Item" action="exampleadditem.php" style="WIDTH: 98px; HEIGHT: 36px" size="18"><td>
    <br/><br/>
    <table border=1  align="center" width="900">
    <tr>
        <th>Item Code<th>Category<th>Item Name<th>Image<th>Description<th>Price (RM)<th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<div id='img_div'>";
                echo "<td width='60'>".$row['item_code']."</td>";
                echo "<td width='80'>".$row['cat_name']."</td>";
                echo "<td width='80'>".$row['item_name']."</td>";
                echo "<td width='65'><img src='img/".$row['image']."'width=30 height=30></td>";
                echo "<td width='250'>".$row['text']."</td>";
                echo "<td width='25'>".$row['price']."</td>";
                echo"<td width='90'><a href='editform.php?item_code=".$row['item_code']."'>Edit</a> | 
                <a href='delete.php?item_code=".$row['item_code']."'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>

    </table>
    </center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

edit: the image name did change to item code in the img folder but in the database it remains the original name.

[Database table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPuNu.jpg)

Comment: First of all, please visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL Injection and how to prevent them. Your code actually is really vulnerable and not safe at all! Your database can be hacked in a few seconds without the need of any deeper knowledge about your system. Always use `prepared statements` when it comes to query with user inputs.

Comment: Well then use the right value in your query …? Looks like `$item_code` holds this id you are talking about - so where is the actual problem now to use _that_ value in your query, instead of something else that you _don’t_  want to use in that place …?

Comment: I have edited to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Twinfriends thanks for the tip but im still quite new to php and sql and just trying to do some code. Im still learning about it though

Comment: @Drew Security is one of the most importanst things on webapplications. Never to early to learn about prepared statements. Its a really easy topic, its learned in around 10 minutes and it makes your code so much safer